# How to insert a titles row into a csv file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a .csv file which has data but not the column headers. I can able to create new .csv file with oldcsv file's content. But I need to add column headers in first row and from second row the existing data should appear.

Here is the code I have written:

```
 Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\sample.csv")      
 Dim ioLine As String      Dim ioLines As String      
 ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine     
 ioLines = ioLine     
 While Not ioLine = ""         
    ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine         
    ioLines = ioLines & vbCrLf & ioLine      
 End While     
 Dim ioWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\new.csv")     
 ioWriter.WriteLine(ioLines)     
 ioFile.Close()     
 ioWriter.Close()
```

Now i need to add column headers in new.csv as "ID","Name","Number","Amount"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the Reader and Writer to read and write within the loop and avoid creating a oiLines construct.

```
Dim reader as New StreamReader(inputFileName)
Dim writer as New StreamWriter(outputFileName)
Dim line as String

'Do you have a definition of what has to be added here?
writer.WriteLine(headerLine)

While (Nothing <> (line = reader.ReadLine()))
  writer.WriteLine(line)
End While

reader.Dispose()
writer.Dispose()
```

Check the code, as I wrote it blind. I am more C#, but the idea is sound. You just need to supply the inputFileName, outputFileName and headerLine. This also allows putting this in a method, where it is reuseable. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun I post this "oneliner", but remember, the shortest is'nt allways the best.
(first import system.io.file):

```
Imports system.io.file
```

Then put this line where you want to fix the file:

```
WriteAllText("c:\new.csv", """ID"",""Name"",""Number"",""Amount""" & vbCrLf & ReadAllText("c:\old.csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\sample.csv")      
 Dim ioLine As String      Dim ioLines As String      
 ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine     
 ioLines = """ID"",""Name"",""Number"",""Amount"""
 ioLines &= vbCrLf & ioLine 
 While Not ioLine = ""         
    ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine         
    ioLines = ioLines & vbCrLf & ioLine      
 End While     
 Dim ioWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\new.csv")     
 ioWriter.WriteLine(ioLines)     
 ioFile.Close()     
 ioWriter.Close()
```

Comment: ioLines = "ID","Name","Number","Amount"

Comment: it's working with the following code  ioLines = "ID,Name,Number,Amount"

Comment: THat's fine - sometimes strings are encapsulated in "" marks in csv files as this allows for commas to be contained in strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Using ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\sample.csv"), ioWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\new.csv")

        ioWriter.WriteLine("ID,Name,Number,Amount")

        Do Until ioFile.Peek = -1

            ioWriter.WriteLine(ioFile.ReadLine)

        Loop

        ioFile.Close()
        ioWriter.Close()

    End Using
```